# C# application fails to call a method from C++ DLL/Project

Tags: c#, c++

I try to integrate Web Camera support into C# solution. 1st of all I have learnt the nice example from Touchless.Vision. It contains C# solution with 3 components :
- one windows form project (C#, Any CPU)
- one wrapper project (C#, Any CPU)
- WebCamLib project (C++, x64)

I use Win7 x64.
So the example works fine. At least from the moment when I changes Platform target from Win32 to x64 for C   library/project.

But then I have added two projects (C# wrapper and C++ project) under another C# solution. Now it always fails when it calls a method from C++ project.

```
System.BadImageFormatException was unhandled by user code
Message="Could not load file or assembly 'WebCamLib, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
Source="Touchless.Vision"
FileName="WebCamLib, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
FusionLog=""
StackTrace:
   at Touchless.Vision.Camera.CameraService.<BuildCameraList>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Touchless.Vision.Camera.CameraService.get_AvailableCameras() in C:\CustomWare.NET\CustomWare\WebCamWrapper\Camera\CameraService.cs:line 40
```

The solution uses AnyCPU platform as well. I think there should not be any conflicts based on platform.

What can be the different between these two cases? What should I check?

Comment: Make sure that there is a "bit-ness" match between C++ DLL and C# app, e.g. if the C++ DLL is built with 32-bit x86, the same should be for the C# DLL, and similar for 64-bit (try to avoid "Any CPU", and instead try to specify an explicit match).

Comment: AnyCPU is really confusing. If I define platform clearly then everything works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that you're calling a 32-bit library from a 64-bit application. When using the AnyCPU configuration on an executable it will load as the OS type. 32-bit on a 32-bit machine, 64-bit on a 64-bit machine.

When calling a 32-bit library from a 64-bit executable there might differences in things like the data types which can lead to serious trouble. For example, C# specifies that a long **is always 64 bits in size** (it's an alias of System.Int64), while in C it's defined as **at least 32 bits in size**.

Or in your case, I assume the opposite applies.

So make sure to check whether your newly added C# library is indeed a AnyCPU or x64 project, and your C project is an x64 project. My guess is that the last one is not the case.

To provide a bit more insight on the subject:

AnyCPU is perfectly fine for # class libraries. It's the calling assembly that determines how to load an assembly. Thus, if you have a 32-bit application on a 64-bit machine calling an AnyCPU class library, it will load as if it were a 32-bit library.

In VS2010 the behavior changed compared to VS2008. When you create a Console, WPF or Forms application the target platform will always be x86 (32-bit). My suggestion is to use x86 unless you absolutely need or want to create a 64-bit version of your application. 64-bit applications have some benefits, and I'm sure that somewhere in the future the use of 32-bit applications will completely disappear, but because maintaining two versions doubles the time necessary to test the software, create releases, test those releases, and so forth, I usually don't bother creating a 64-bit version.

Rick Byers wrote an interesting article on this a while ago: [AnyCPU Exes are usually more trouble than they're worth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2009/06/09/anycpu-exes-are-usually-more-trouble-then-they-re-worth.aspx).

Comment: AnyCPU is really confusing. If I define platform clearly then everything works. Thank you very much.